# java - need to import private key from jks(java keystore)

Tags: java, jwt, private-key, jks

I have a stored my certificate in Java KeyStore which is required for accessing Restful API. To access this API I need to create JWT (Json Web Token) which I am implementing in Java. For generating JWT I need to sign the payload with given private key.
So, what I am doing is, importing private key from .jks file into my code

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/file.jks");
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keystore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());  
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("key", "".toCharArray());
JWTClaimsSet claimsSetOne = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                .subject("alias")
                .issueTime(new Date(123000L))
                .issuer("https://issuer")
                .audience("https://audience")
                .build();

JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(privateKey);
SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT (new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256), claimsSetOne);
signedJWT.sign(signer);
String orderOne = signedJWT.serialize();
```

Now, with this piece of code, It returns private key as "null" value. which results into failure of my code.
So, what could be my code so that I can read private key to sign the payload to generate JWT.
Or any other alternative to achieve same.
Thanks in advance.
Edit :
Then I tried this command,

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/sho1.jks");
InputStream   is = new FileInputStream(file);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String password = "sho123";
keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEnt = 
   (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keystore.getEntry("sho",new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray()));
PrivateKey privateKey = keyEnt.getPrivateKey();
```

It gives me error as Invalid_Signature.

Comment: How did you import the key in your keystore ? is "key" the alias used when importing your key ?

Comment: I got a .pfx file. Then using keytool command, I imported that in java keystore.

Comment: And you are sure that "key" is the alias of your private key ?

Comment: Now look at the edited code. where "sho" is the alias we have given to our jks.

Comment: Invalid_Signature is return by the server ? Or is it thrown by the provided code ?

Comment: Above code is generating the JWT. But when you hit it to server with that JWT, its gives error as invalid_Signature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136522/discussion-between-vatsal-mehta-and-jey).

Comment: Please post the server code that validates the JWT using the public key

Comment: For time being, I am generating token with https://jwt.io/#debugger ; adding my required header,payload & private Key.

Comment: Do you mean you are building the JWT with Java and validating the JWT in jwt.io with `Invalid_Signature` message?

Comment: No, hitting to actual API where I am getting Invalid_Signature. I am using jwt.io just to verify the encoded code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong in the implementation of JAVA code. This code works fine. Error which I getting as INVALID_SIGNATURE is due to JKS. The certificate which I importing that is not the proper i.e. It does not have  correct certificate path. I tried importing correct way then it works.
So make sure in this type of scenario you are importing certificate with correct keypair to get correct fingerprint in the JKS.
Thanks all.